# Pull "Hottest Questions" from OSQA

Tags: django, osqa

I want to pull a feed of "hottest" questions from my OSQA installation(installed on a subdomain of my main site) and show it on my main site. Is there a way to do that?

One way could be through the RSS Feed. Is there a RSS Feed just for the 'hottest' questions section?

UPDATE:

I originally asked this in Nov, 2012. 2 Years later, I still cant find an easy answer? Any improvements?

Comment: OSQA does not provide a 'hottest' questions rss feed by default. You would need to write your own.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSQA does not provide a 'hottest' questions rss feed by default. You would need to write your own.

I'd start by looking at

- `question_list` function in `forum/views/readers.py`
- `HottestQuestionsSort` helper in `forum/views/readers.py`
- `RSSQuestionFeed` helper in `forums/feed.py`